# pick up files from remote server and then delete

Tags: expect

I have an expect script that retrieves files from a remote location based on a pattern and places them in the current directory. After The transfer I want to delete the files that were retrieved from the remote location. My script does an MGET and does the transfer. I tried using the RM command based on the pattern that was used to perform the MGET to remove the files, but I can remove more than I retrieved. Can you help me to only delete the files that i retrieved from the remote location?

$env(SSH_FILE)\r" is the pattern variable in the script. Ex: .835

```
 sftp> rm *.835*                                             
 Removing /EdifecsFTP/Inbound835/W6BA/90404B277947nCOR0.835  
 Removing /EdifecsFTP/Inbound835/W6BA/90404B277947nCORS.835
```

I DON"T WANT TO DELETE BASED ON THE PATTERN.

```
send "CD $env(SSH_CDIR)\r"
expect "No such file or directory"    {quit;exit 1}
send "LCD $env(SSH_LCD)\r"
expect "path name does not exist"     {quit;exit 1}
send "mget $env(SSH_FILE)\r"

send "rm $env(SSH_FILE)\r"
```

Comment: Are the newly downloaded files going to be the **only** files in $end(SSH_LCD)?

Comment: No they are not.  There could be many different files.

Comment: Can you provide the code to create a list of files that were transferred, and use the list to select the files to delete.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is:

- after mget completes, get the list of files in the local directory that match the pattern:

  ```
  set local_files [glob -directory $env(SSH_LCD) -tails $env(SSH_FILE)
  ```
- and delete any remote file name that matches:

  ```
  foreach f $local_files {
      send "rm $f\r"
      expect $prompt
  }
  ```

Comment: I tried the code you suggested. I pick up 2 files from the remote server, but only 1 file is removed.

Comment: Here is the log.                                                                                         sftp> rm 90404B277947AACORS.835                                                
 rm 90404B277947AACOR0.835                                                      
 Removing /EdifecsFTP/Inbound835/W6BA/90404B277947AACORS.835                    
 sftp>

Comment: Here is the code.                                                                                        set local_files [glob -directory $env(SSH_LCD) -tails $env(SSH_FILE)]
set timeout 120
expect "sftp>"
foreach f $local_files {
   send "rm $f\r"
set timeout 120
   #--expect $prompt
    #-  puts "$f"
}
expect "sftp>"

Comment: What you suggested work, thanks. I changed it to expect "sftp>" ,after the  send "rm $f\r" . However the local directory contains many files so local_files loops many times, because the files in the local directory are not being deleted.  Do you have any other suggestions  that can be  tried?  I'm new to expect scripting